# How does the eukaryotic cell synthesize all of the proteins of a protein complex (like ETC complex I) at stoichiometric ratios/numbers?

Tags: proteins

(eg synthesize all proteasome proteins at the appropriate ratios to which they are used)

How often are proteins of the same complex (eg all the proteins of the 20S/19S parts of the proteasome or complex I of ETC) controlled by the same enhancers/promoters? Is it often the case that you just have non-stoichiometric synthesis and then the cell degrades the excess protein if it can't put them both together?

Comment: You seem to have reputation here, so you should know that you are expected to demonstrate that you have done some research before asking questions here. This is a complex question, the answer to which differs between eukaryotes and prokaryotes (e.g. for ribosomal proteins) and probably between organisms and protein complexes. Tell us what you find when you search for something like “coordinate regulation of ribosomal protein synthesis” or whatever.